# do I really need to have an event handler for URLLoader?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to actionscript, and I am following a tutorial by Joseph Devore. I understand that when I want to do a network query I can create a URLRequest, and send this with a URLLoader. I expected to find the response data in the URLLoader.data attribute, but after making the query this was still null in my case. Then it seemed that I must create an event handling to actually access the response. Is this true?

I wrote this small example code, and wonder how I (the easiest way) can access the response in this get request.

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class stackQuery
    {
        public function stackQuery()
        {
        }

        public function makeQuery(): String {
            var request: URLRequest = URLRequest("http://www.google.com");
            var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleResponse);
            try{
                loader.load(request);
            }
            if(loader.data == null){
                 return "Empty"
            }
            return "data not empty"
            }

            private function handleResponse(event:Event):void
            {
                //something with event.target.data here??
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any nice way to do a synchronous load (like you can in some other languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any nice way to do a synchronous load (like you can in some other languages) with AS3.  Your data is null because in AS3 the load command is asynchronous - meaning it doesn't halt the rest of the application (locking it up) until the load completes, it moves on to the next line of code and dispatches an event once the load is complete.

Here is a code example of how you would want to handle this based off of the code you supplied:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class stackQuery
    {
        private var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader(); //let's move it out to the class level so you can easily reference it from other methods (though this is purely optional)

        public function stackQuery()
        {
        }

        public function makeQuery(): String {
            var request:URLRequest = URLRequest("http://www.google.com");


            //add you listeners before loading
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleResponse);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleResponse); //it's good practice to also listen for errors
            loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleResponse); //this kind of error will happen if you're trying to load a local resource but have published as network only (or vice-versa)

            //load the request, any code after this will run before the load completes. 
            loader.load(request);
        }

            //this function will run once the load completes
        private function handleResponse(event:Event):void
        {
            if (event is IOErrorEvent) {
                //you had an IO error, better do something 
                return;
            }

            if (event is SecurityErrorEvent) {
                //url wasn't allowed to load
                return;
            }

            trace(loader.data); //this is what was returned from the page
                //you could also get it by referencing the currentTarget of the event
                trace(URLLoader(event.currentTarget).data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is true. Imagine you load one megabyte of data. You need time in order to load it, right? So there's no way that you will have this data on the very next line of code.

The listener will get executed when the target dispatches the event - in your case when that megabyte is loaded.

This is a normal behavior.

Comment: so what should I add in the handleResponse() so that the makeQuery() will return the string "data not empty"?

Comment: What @Andrey is saying is that you can't expect to return anything meaningful from `makeQuery`.

Comment: @marcela. That means that makeQuery actually have time to finish before handleResponse is called?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You call `makeQuery`, but it takes let's say a few seconds before the `handleResponse` is executed (time depends on many factors, but certainly not instant). What you should do is to add listener to that class and wait for event, much like: `stackQuery.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done); stackQuery.makeQuery();`

Comment: ok, then I might understand why a second URLLoader is used in handleResponse (or equivalent) in the tutorials...

Comment: Just to mention, that it's not a second loader, it's just casting the `event.target` to such, because the `handleResponse` gets an event as a parameter, and this event contains all the information needed - what type is it (loaded or not), the loader itself, the loaded data, etc.

Comment: This is not correct. This is not a "normal behavior" as you say but a design choice. Like I said some languages are synchronous by design and loading any size of data will still be available on the next line of code (and idle the execution of code if need be). There's nothing normal or not normal about the two systems, it's just a design.

Comment: It's a "normal behavior" and this will happen when you execute it WITHIN Action Script (the question we're talking about). And it's a **normal** thing to happen in this language. If it's "normal", "regular" or anything else outside of the scope, can be answered only by a magician :)

Answer (score 1):

While the answers given are correct, the real explanation is that Actionscript 3 is an asynchronous language as opposed to other language like Python for example that are synchronous. In python after loading something like an url the next line of code will not be executed until the url is loaded (which can create lag or idling execution), in Actionscript 3 the code execution doesn't wait and move on to the next line. That is the reason you need to use events (Actionscript 3 is an event based language) so you can find out when the data you are waiting for is available all that while your code is still executing.

Comment: Action Script **is** synchronous language with asynchronous capabilities, such as the Event system. And this particular question is pretty good example of using asynchronous calls. But if you don't deal with events, mostly everything is a synchronous.